# All the characters on $S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, characters

Would anyone please give me a hint to find all the  characters on  $S^1$?

By characters I mean complex valued functions on $ S ^ 1 $ that their values have norm $1 $ and they  satisfy:
$f (x+y)=f (x)  f (y) $

Please note that although there are some similar questions(i'vé seen them ), but it is not a duplicate.

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group#Representations